# Source Tree: Not able to push to my remote repo in GitHub

Tags: git, github, atlassian-sourcetree, git-lfs

I'm working in a game in Unreal and my first commits where pushing without problem, then came a moment where was not possible anymore. This message is appearing after I try to push:

```
batch response: Bad credentials sourcetree
```

I'm tracking some files with LFS, I don't know if that have something to do. My last move trying to solve this problem (but not one of my best moves) was removing the remote repository path I was using and re-adding it, now the tag which indicates where my remote commits were no longer exists.

Another suspicion that I have is over my internet connection. I live in Venezuela, the internet is awful here and maybe the root of the problem is there along the big amount of data processed with LFS.

Please help!

Comment: Are you sure you provided the correct login details? The correct Username and Passowrd?

Comment: What's the full output when you pushed to remote?

Comment: @ifconfig Yes, because was working at the begining, I was able to push my first 5 commits. But I could re-enter both to prove it, How can I have access to the Username and Password to edited again?

Answer (score 2):

To edit the username and password in SourceTree, you can use below way:

SourceTree -> Tools -> Options -> Authentication Tab.

- If you only need to change the password for account, you can edit the item under **Saved Passwords**.
- If you need to change both username and password, you can edit the item under **Accounts**. Then you can specify username and refresh password.

  [image]

Comment: Thank you! I didn't answer your previous question because I made the problem worse and double click "master" in the branch option in my SourceTree the left panel; now all my project went to a very early version..... I'm a disaster. The branch I was working on doesn't show in the graphic so apparently I loose almost everything. Let me try to push again after reorganizing myself and send you the required output.